# Does Socket IO involve Disk IO?

Tags: linux, file, sockets, io

If one process sends data through a socket to another process on the same machine how likely is it that a disk read/write will occur during transmission? There seems to be a socket file type, are these guaranteed to be in memory provided there is free memory?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your design and requirement ?

Comment: There isn't really a specific design. I'm trying to gauge the performance of a flat file cms like pico against something similarly simple that uses an all in memory database like redis. I recall reading years ago in a MSDN article about winsock that it used a file to implement posix. At least thats what I remember, I had a vague notion that maybe a disk write could occur on some systems. Because if a blocking disk write occurs during IPC then that's game over for any database, in terms of speed, even if the whole thing is in memory.

Comment: @Kaan I suggest you find your source and read it again. Your memory seems to have failed you.

Comment: I think this question is well worth answering and it's a pity people are not seeing this. Maybe the answer is OS-dependent. Obviously also, being implemented as files in Win32 does not mean they are disk-backed files. Obviously nobody expects socket I/O to involve disk I/O. But maybe there are implications from the POSIX spec, maybe guarantees... It's late in the night, I'm seeing disk activity at a place where apparently there are only sockets, and I don't know if I should grab Bach's book or the "Design of the 4.4BSD OS" or the POSIX specs... A good answer would have book references.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly. TCP / UDP network sockets, over localhost, or a UNIX Domain Socket will operate in memory. UNIX Domain Sockets are typically the fastest option outside of dropping into kernel space with a module.

sockets over localhost pipes are nearly as simple as a couple of memcpy's between userspace and kernel space and back. In TCP case, you have the stack overhead.

Both files and sockets share the kernel abstraction of descriptor table, but that doesn't imply an actual file.

Of course, the database may trigger some write to a log, as a result of your transaction.

Answer (score 9):

In the POSIX model, as well as many other kernels, files are not only in disks.  Instead, every device is represented by a "special file".  They live in directories or some sort of namespace, but accessing them is not disk access, even if they are placed in a directory on disk.

If you have memory pressure, then it's possible for some of your data buffers to get swapped out.  But this has nothing to do with the "file" nature of devices.  It's just using the disk as additional RAM.

So "Yes, socket I/O is file I/O, but not disk read/write."

Answer (score 5):

Grabbing the "Design of the 4.4BSD Operating System", which describes what can be considered the reference implementation, sections 11.2 "implementation structure" and 11.3 "memory management", and in the absense of extreme memory pressure, it appears to be guaranteed that there will be no disk I/O involved in transmission.

Data transmitted is stored in special structures, mbufs and mbuf clusters, data is added or removed at either end of each buffer, directly. Probably the same buffers will be used over and over, being freed to a specific pool and then reallocated from there. Fresh buffers are allocated from the kernel malloc pool, which is not swappable. Growth of the number of buffers will obviously only occur when the consumer is slow and up to a limit.

Put simply, as to the data, in the reference implementation these buffers are not backed by files, much less by a file in the file system where the inode is placed, at best they would be backed by swap space, even if extremely unlikely to be paged out.

This only leaves out meta data and status information which may be on the inode. Naturally, inode creation and lookup will cause disk access. As to status, all I can think of is atime.

I can't find authoritative information regarding atime on UNIX domain sockets. But I tried on FreeBSD and on Linux and all four file times were always kept as the inode creation time. Even establishing a second connection to a UNIX domain socket does not seem to update atime.