# Performance of Socket write vs disk write

Tags: java, performance, sockets, logging

My java application logs a fair amount of information to a logfile on disk.  Some of this logged information is more important than the rest; except that in rare cases the less-important info is needed to explain to the end-user why the code in production took a certain decision.

I was wondering if it will be a good idea to log the less important information to a socket instead of the file on disk. Is socket write significantly faster than disk write?

Update: Basically, I wanted to log to a socket in the same subnet or even the same machine, assuming that it would be faster than writing to disk.  Another process (not part of my application) would then read from that socket at its convenience.  I was thinking this would be logstash pulling from a socket. Async logging to disk using another thread is another alternative but I wanted to consider the socket option first if that is an easy solution with minimal performance hit.

Comment: Where will this socket be opened to?  Socket is I/O, Disk is I/O.  I will guess that both are probably extremely slow.  Perhaps it is better to put your logging into a low priority thread so that it doesn't disturb your running time if the logging is causing performance issues?

Comment: If the disk write is a fully RAM cached Optane SSD and the socket is dialup connection bounced via four satellites to an Antarctic outpost, the disk write is way faster. If the disk write is to a sync mounted floppy disk and the socket is via the loopback device and whose consumer just does a zero-copy transfer to RAM, the socket is way faster.

Comment: The most important question is, have you noticed a performance hit?

Comment: disk is *usually* faster: https://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks    Modern logging frameworks are asynchronous in nature so log statements cost very little. Upgrade your logging: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

Comment: If you are worried about performance, your first check would be if you are buffering the writes to disk (eg using `BufferedOutputStream` or `BufferedWriter`).

Comment: Am also going through same requirement, I would prefer use Async SocketAppender send data to local log Collector application . Then Logstash would fetch from Collector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have few choices:

- [local storage is *usually* faster than network](https://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks)
- [you could use async logging to disk](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html), so your process fires and forgets (which is fast!)
- **logstash** can read from **Unix Domain Sockets**, if you are on ***nix**; [these are *usually* faster than I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568562/does-socket-io-involve-disk-io)

If you are writing somewhere fast and from there it is being forwarded in a slower fashion (logstash logging over network to some Elastic instance) where is the buffering happening? Such setup will generate growing backlog of messages yet to be shipped if the logging happens at high rate for prolonged period of time.

---

In the above scenarios buffering will happen (respectively):

- **direct sync write to disk**: final log **file on the disk** is the buffer
- **async logging framework**: buffers could eat into your heap or process memory (when outside of heap, or in some kernel area, therefore in **RAM**)
- **unix domain sockets**: buffered in the kernel space, so **RAM** again

In the last 2 options things will get increasingly creaky in constant high volume scenario.

Test and profile...
or just log to the local disk and rotate the files, deleting old ones.

Comment: diginoise. thanks for your insights. In the 3rd link you mentioned above, it is not clear that socket i/o is usually faster than disk i/o - say on the same machine.  I will run a benchmark to compare the performance of the Async write option to socket write on same machine.

Comment: @Don quoting from the 1st answer of 3rd link: "UNIX Domain Sockets are typically the fastest option outside of dropping into kernel space with a module". I named these **POSIX/BSD IPC sockets** - will rename to **Unix Domain Sockets**

Answer (score 2):

Socket is not a destination. It's a transport. Your question "send data to socket" should therefore be rephrased to "send data to network", "send data to disk" or "send data to another process".

In all these cases, socket itself is unlikely to be a bottleneck. The bottleneck will be either network, disk or application CPU usage - depending on where you are actually sending your data from the socket. On OS level, sockets are usually implemented as zero-copy mechanism, which means that the data is just passed to the other side as a pointer and is therefore highly efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my update to my question.

Comment: Hm, even after update, it's still not clear to me what exactly is the problem you are experiencing. It seems like you are concerned about logging performance, but the term "socket" is really just a special file name. It doesn't have anything to do with either the problem or solution. If you are asking about performance, is a question of how exactly your software works and what hardware you have.